# Fluxxor: How to access data in one store from another?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

In Fluxxor. I have a getter method on one store. In this method I want to get some data from another store.

In Store1:

```
getData = function() {
    dataFromOtherStore = Store2.getData()
    return dataFromThisStore +  dataFromOtherStore

}
```

(I am using waitFor in my action handler so I know that the data is there in Store2)

How do I reference Store2 from Store1?

Answer (score 1):

In Store1

```
store2 = this.flux.store("Store2")
dataFromOtherStore = store2.getMethod()
```